# Вывод данных в angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

При выводе данных в html

```
<div >
    {{ row.details}}
 </div>
```

Получаю `[object Object]`, можно ли как сделать вывод ключ : значение, не используя конкретное указание полей к примеру `{{ row.details.Printers}}` , то есть  модифицировав только row.details ,что бы отображалось как

```
Printers :3500, 3050, 3000 Series
Material: Board 
....
```

[image: details]
    [image: details]

Comment: `{{ row.details | raw }}` кажется такой фильтр есть в ангуляре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Angular есть [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe). Использование очень простое и описано детально в документации.

В вашем случае достаточно пропустить объект `row.details` через этот конвеер:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of row.details | keyvalue">
  // `item` это объект у которого есть свойства `key` и `value`
  <div *ngFor="let product of item.value">
    {{ product }}
  <div>
</ng-container>
```

Альтернатива - это в компоненте объявить метод `getKeysForDetails`, который будет возвращать список ключей для объекта `row.details`:

```
public getKeysForDetails = (details) => Object.keys(details);
```

И использовать в шаблоне должным образом:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let key of getKeysForDetails(row.details)">
  <div *ngFor="let product of row.details[key]">{{ product }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Мое личное мнение - используйте первый вариант с конвеером (пайпом). У конвееров есть определенное поведение под капотом и они часто используются для бустинга производительности.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё получилось

Answer (score 0):

Есть pipe json

{{ row.details | json }}